# Passing id to button action method in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have UIButtons programatically created. Now, I created an method to trigger for the button like so:

```
-(void)createButton {
//code to create button
[mybutton addTarget:self action:@selector(myAction:)forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

-(void)myAction:(id)sender {
if([tag sender] == 0) {
posX = 380;
} else if(....... //set posX to different values
}
[self.myScroll setContentOffset:CGPointMake(poxX, 0) animated:YES];
```

That's pretty much what the buttons do aside from loading data. Basically, I am using the buttons as tabs. If I tap on a button, it slides to the center. In one of these buttons, there's an "update buttons" button where I can add and remove more buttons. If I tap on one of the buttons, it would automatically be removed and if I tap add, one would automatically add. There's no problem with that. The thing is, I want to retain the "update buttons" button centered as it is technically still the selected button. Here's how the method inside the view for update buttons:

```
-(void)updateButtons {
NSUInteger index = [self.anArray indexOfObject:@"btnChange"];
id indexId = [NSNumber numberWithInteger: index];
//this following line causes the app to crash because it does not recognize the indexId I'm trying to set
[self myAction:indexId];
}
```

Everytime I execute the updateButtons function and myAction is triggered, the app crashes with an uncaught exception. So my question is, how can I properly pass an id to an action method?

Comment: what does the error say? usually the sender should be the button itself. not a nsnumber instance. also why would you try to trigger `myAction:` from `updateButtons`? it should only be triggered by the button.

Comment: show me the code inside myAction

Answer (score 1):

Precise answer to your question is: pass nil for the sender parameter:

```
 [self myAction:nil];
```

Comment: as we do not have the method body we cannot know if this will work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

```
 -(void)createButton 
{
    //code to create button
    myButton.tag  = 1; 
    [mybutton addTarget:self action:@selector(myAction:)forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

-(void)myAction:(id)sender {
    //do something here
}
```

you are trying to pass the NSNumber object but you need to pass the UIButton object to `myAction:` method, I think you should create the UIButton object in the .h file and add tag to the button and pass the reference of that button object to the method

```
-(void)updateButtons 
{
    NSUInteger index = [self.anArray indexOfObject:@"btnChange"];
    if(myButton.tag == index){

       [self myAction:myButton];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)updateButtons {
NSUInteger index = [self.anArray indexOfObject:@"btnChange"];
mybutton.tag=index
[self myAction:nil];
}
```

then in

```
-(void)myAction:(id)sender {
//do something here
int index=[sender tag]; //this is your index
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
-(void)createButton 
 {
    //code to create button
    [mybutton addTarget:self action:@selector(myAction:)forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 }

  -(void)myAction:(id)sender
  {
    //do something here
  }

 -(void)updateButtons 
 {
    NSUInteger index = [self.anArray indexOfObject:@"btnChange"];
    id indexId = [NSNumber numberWithInteger: index];
    [self myAction:mybutton];//if u r using my button  else u can use
    [self myAction:nil]
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`id` in Objective-C just means any object—it's used to avoid specifying a certain type of object. When using target-action, the first argument is the `sender`, or the object that sent the action. For the buttons, the sender would be an instance of `UIButton`.

I would recommend adding `NSLog(@"%@",sender);` to your action method to see what type it is each time the method is called.

So what should be passed as the argument? Well, it depends on what `myAction` does, and you'll have to share that code to get more details on this. If `myAction` doesn't use the `sender` argument, you can safely pass `nil` as other answerers suggest.

Note that when you use target-action, if you're not using the `sender` argument, you can leave it off altogether. Just declare your method like this:

```
-(void)myAction
{
    // code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[mybutton addTarget:self action:@selector(myAction:)forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Instead of above, replace this below line

```
[mybutton addTarget:self action:@selector(myAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, seems weird that you are using `-addTarget:action:forState.` `UIButton` is a concrete subclass of `UIControl` and as such, instead uses the method `-addTarget:action:forControlEvents:`
which can take a variable number of or-able `UIControlEvent` enums. Specifically, the ones you want for a `UIButton` would be of the subtype `UIControlEventTouch...`.

You should be crashing right away just cause that method doesn't exist.

That being said, without looking at your code we can't really tell you exactly which line inside your `-myAction:` method causes the crash. But the important point here is, the method whose signature / selector you are registering via the target-action pattern doesn't necessarily even need to have a parameter of type `id`, `UIButton` or anything.

Basically, when you do `-addTarget:action:forControlEvents:`you are telling a subclass of UIControl that when it undergoes the desired event/s, it should invoke a method in the object you pass to the first parameter of `-addTarget:` (the target), whose signature is the selector you pass to `action:`. The selector you pass to this parameter can have one or zero parameters in turn. If you pass in one with none (say, your action method is `-doSomething`), when the `UIControl` responds to the `UIControlEvent` it'll simply call your method and that's that. If instead, you pass in a selector that takes one parameter, the `UIControl` that triggered the action is automatically passed in to that parameter, cast to whatever type your action method's parameter type is.

So for instance:

if you register like so:

```
[self.readingListButton addTarget:self action:@selector(doSomething) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

your action method would look like this:

```
- (void)doSomething
{
    //  Notice we don't have a parameter and so we are limited to doing stuff
    //  that does not require the sender to be passed in.
    NSLog(@"do Something!");
}
```

If instead you register like this (notice the **:** in the selector):

```
[self.readingListButton addTarget:self action:@selector(doSomething:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

You could go:

```
- (void)doSomething:(id)sender
{
    //  If the button triggers the method, sender will be an id pointer holding the memory
    //  address of a UIButton and we could cast it to UIButton like so: UIButton *b = (UIButton)sender
    // Then again, sender might not be a button. As long as we stick to stuff that any object
    // will respond to we are fine though.
    NSLog(@"do Something! %@", sender);
}
```

or:

```
- (void)doSomething:(UIButton*)sender
{
    //  We straight out assume it is a button:
    NSLog(@"do Something! %@", sender);
}
```

So as you can see, the choice of parameter vs no parameter and the parameter type is sort of up to you.

Now my guess is the reason why your code crashes is because when you manually call the action method you are passing it an `NSNumber` instead of a `UIButton`and inside the method you do something with the parameter that treats it as a `UIBUtton.`

Think about this for instance:

```
- (void)doSomething:(UIButton*)sender
{
    //  Our parameter is a button, so we can totally change its state:
    sender.selected = !sender.selected;
}
```

If you pass in a button to the above method, it'll work just fine. However in your second case, you pass a number. and what really happens is this:

```
    NSNumber *n;
    UIButton *b = (UIButton*)n;
    [target doSomething:b];
```

And inside `-doSomething:`

```
- (void)doSomething:(UIButton*)sender
{
    //  Our parameter is a button, so we can totally change its state:
    sender.selected = !sender.selected;
}
```

But `sender` now is not really a button. It's a number cast to button. The minute the code above tries to change the state, it attempts to call the method `-setState:` on a `NSNumber` which does not have that method, and so you'd get a classic exception along the lines of:
**unrecognized selector sent to instance.**

So bottom line, if you don't require to pass in the button or any info into the target method, just define it without parameters or, if you do require a parameter, either make the parameter polymorphic (type `id`) and inside your method check to see what it is and act accordingly, or stick to a parameter of type `UIButton` but them make sure you only call it passing in buttons.